# Python Regex - Reject strings with newline

Tags: python, regex, newline

I want to match complete strings to a specific pattern. Let's say :

```
word = "aaaa"
test = re.match(r"^aaaa$", word) # this returns True
```

However, if the word is followed by a newline character :

```
word = "aaaa\n"
test = re.match(r"^aaaa$", word) # Also returns True :(
```

But I want to find a way for it to return False in this last case. Is there a way to differentiate "\n"?

Comment: There can be easy way, but `^aaaa(?=(?!\n)$)` will work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of anchors `^` and `$` use `\A` for start and `\Z` for end:

```
>>> print re.match(r'\Aaaaa\Z', 'aaaa')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1014b9bf8>

>>> print re.match(r'\Aaaaa\Z', 'aaaa\n')
None
```

`\A` matches the actual start of string and `\Z` the actual end and there can be only one of `\A` and `\Z` in a multiline string, whereas `$` may be matched in each line.

I suggest [reading this very good article on permanent line anchors.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Just fyi unlike `.NET`, `Java`, `PCRE`, `Delphi`, `PHP` in `Python` `\Z` matches only at the very end of the string. **Python does not support `\z`**.

Comment: Amazing. Don't know how I missed that! Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `negative lookaheads` for checking if it contains a new line character or not.In your case, `^aaaa(?!\n)$`.